# Get a specific tag - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the xml that I'm trying to parse.

```
<url>
   <loc>https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-chanderi-pleated-sharara-pants-177/iprdt</loc>
   <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://img.faballey.com/Images/Product/IPL00325Z/d3.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>Green Chanderi Pleated Sharara Pants</image:title>
   </image:image>
   <priority>0.8</priority>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-foil-chanderi-kurta-171/iprdt</loc>
   <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://img.faballey.com/Images/Product/ITN01710Z/d3.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>Aqua Foil Chanderi Kurta</image:title>
   </image:image>
   <priority>0.8</priority>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

I need to get text of only `<loc>` tags. So, I do the following:-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features='xml')
loc = soup.find('loc')
while loc is not None:
    url = loc.text
    yield url
    loc = loc.find_next('loc')
```

The result I get is

1. `https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-chanderi-pleated-sharara-pants-177/iprdt`
2. `https://img.faballey.com/Images/Product/IPL00325Z/d3.jpg`
3. `https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-foil-chanderi-kurta-171/iprdt`
4. `https://img.faballey.com/Images/Product/ITN01710Z/d3.jpg`

However, what I want is only `https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-chanderi-pleated-sharara-pants-177/iprdt`, and `https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-foil-chanderi-kurta-171/iprdt`. I don't want the text of `<image:loc>`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS` selectors even in XML document, so select all `url > loc`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """
... your XML from question here ...
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "html.parser")

for loc in soup.select("url > loc"):
    print(loc.text)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-chanderi-pleated-sharara-pants-177/iprdt
https://www.houseofindya.com/aqua-foil-chanderi-kurta-171/iprdt
```

Comment: Why use `html.parser`? Isn't it recommended to use an XML parser when the the content is XML?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast depends on your use case, some XML are malformed so that `html.parser` can be an option. But you can try `xml`. In your example is missing root element so I used `html.parser`